# How to make multiple list in one UITableView? IOS Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

could someone help me. I segmented the UITableView to two the `registered` and the `unregistered` this is my view look like

[image]

but I dont know how to plot my json data into this. This is my data

`[
    {
        "itemName": "Glass 101",
        "status": 1
    },
    {
        "itemName": "Glass 102",
        "status": 0
    },
    {
        "itemName": "Glass 103",
        "status": 0
    },
    {
        "itemName": "Glass 104",
        "status": 1
    },
    {
        "itemName": "Glass 105",
        "status": 0
    },
    {
        "itemName": "Glass 106",
        "status": 1
    }
]`

What I need to do if the status is equal to `0` I put it in `not registered` then if `1` I put it to `registered`.

What I had right now is the simple list, a one list for both registered and not registered. I wonder how could I achieve this.

Any comment or suggestion or links would do big help cos I don't know how to start. Thanks in advance

Comment: you have only two status right(0 or 1) ?

Comment: Filter your JSON into two arrays - Look into `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` and then use the appropriate array for each table section

Comment: yes sir 0 for not registered, and 1 for registered @AkashShinde

Comment: @Paulw11 i could do the filter of array, but I don't know how could I display it in each table section

Comment: Just use the appropriate array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfRowsInSection`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets consider your data is stored in a array named tempArray. Then do this:

```
NSMutableArray *registered = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *notRegistered = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0 ; i < tempArray.count ; i++) {
    if ([[[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"status"] boolValue]) {
        [registered addObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    else{
        [notRegistered addObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

Then in UITableView's `numberOfRowsInSection` do this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 1){
        return registered.count;
    }
    return notRegistered.count;
}
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
    }
    if (indexpath.section == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[notRegistered objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] objectForKey:@"itemName"];
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[registered objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] objectForKey:@"itemName"];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: that's a quite pretty code for Identifying which is which, thanks for that sir. However what is missing right now is the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath, I don't know how could I display the name

Comment: I am adding this. Wait

Answer (score 2):

**Implement this data source method.**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
     return 2;
}
```

use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` to get two different array object one will be for **status 0** and one will be for **status 1**

**Then implement this method.**

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   if(section == 0){
    return [statusZero count]
   }
   else{
   return [statusOne count]
   }
}
```

**Finally add cell using this method**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if(indexPath.section == 0){
   // add status 1 array cell
}
else{
  // add status 0 array cell
}
 return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your json and create two Array as per your condition, `status = 0` , put whole object of current index in `not_registered_Array`, if `status == 1`, put whole object for current index in `registered_Array`

```
NSMutableArray *registered_Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //Define this, out of any method, may be above `viewDidLoad`
NSMutableArray *not_registered_Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0 ; i < yourRespomseArray.count ; i++) {
    if ([[[yourRespomseArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"status"] boolValue]) {
        [registered_Array addObject:[yourRespomseArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    else{
        [not_registered_Array addObject:[yourRespomseArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

From that 2 array, you can return number of row as per section and set the cell value from that.

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    println(prefs.valueForKey("CAT_ID"))
    if (section == 0 ){
        return not_registered_Array.count
    }else{
        return registered_Array.count
    }
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell : UITableViewCell =  ...
    if (section == 0 ){
        let dicObject:NSDictionary = not_registered_Array.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
        cell.textLabel?.text = dicObject.valueForKey("itemName")
    }else{
        let dicObject:NSDictionary = registered_Array.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
        cell.textLabel?.text = dicObject.valueForKey("itemName")
    }
    return cell
}
```

HTH, Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: so thats what I'm missing! thanks for this big help.

Comment: - this should get a plus too for writing it in swift

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if you are unable to parse the JSON to an object or that you don't know how to split up a `UITableView` in multiple sections.

Depending on the usage of the objects, you either need to parse the JSON and instantiate objects with the values that are in your Dictionary (every record in your array could simply fit in a `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`). For example, see this:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial

I am not saying this is the best way to parse JSON to an object, but a way to get you started.

Filter the array to two arrays on the property, using `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`. So something like this:

```
let myCompleteArray = {};
var registered = myCompleteArray.filter ({ $0.status == true });
var unregistered = myCompleteArray.filter( { $0.status == false });
```

Then you need to implement your `UITableViewDataSource`, with something like this:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if (section == 0) {
        return registered.count;
    }
    else {
        return unregistered.count;
    }
}
```

And of course you need to alter your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to check which section is being rendered (just like in the `numberOfRowsInSection` above.

Comment: this line was clever `myCompleteArray.filter ({ $0.status == true })` thanks for this